# Clarification on Google Authentication and Authorization, with OAuth in 2022

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I am writing an App and am trying to leverage Google for A&A.  The app itself relies on access to the users Google Calendar, and so initially I leveraged their updated OAUTH2 library for A&A.

Here is my flow:

User goes to the index.html which has "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" script and google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient is called with my client_id, scopes, redirect url

```
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
    <script>
      let client;
      function initClient() {
        client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
          client_id: 'xxxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          scope:
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile \
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email \
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly \
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events',
          ux_mode: 'redirect',
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback',
        });
      }
      // Request an access token
      function getAuthCode() {
        client.requestCode();
      }
```

The user clicks the login button, which kicks off requestCode() and they begin the login flow.  They login or select their google account, then besides the unapproved app screen, they get to the consent screen with my requested scopes.

After, they are redirected to my expressjs endpoint and using the "googleapis" library I exchange with id_token for the access and refresh tokens.

```
...
 const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code); //exchange code for tokens
  const userInfo = (
    await oauth2Client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: tokens.id_token,
      audience: config.google.clientID,
    })
  ).payload;

  if (!indexBy.email[userInfo.email]) { // check if user exists 
    const newUser = {
      name: userInfo.name,
      email: userInfo.email,
      o_id: userInfo.sub,
      picture: userInfo.picture,
      r_token: tokens.refresh_token,
    };
...
```

Ok, all good.... but not quite.  The problem is, that next time the user wants to login to the app, they go through the entire flow again, including the consent screen (again).

So, after going through more docs, even looking at examples from google.  I was surprised and I noticed that many of those apps used the passport oauth2 plugin :(  Something i've done in the past, but was hoping to avoid that with the recently updated Google client and nodejs libraries.

Ok, how to not prompt for consent screen on subsequent logins?

Maybe separate A&A, so first I use "Sign In With Google" for Authentication, then when I get the user info, check if the user is already registered (hence I have already saved the refresh token) and they start the app.

On the other hand, if they are new (not in existing app user collection), after authenticating, I will then call the OAUTH2 authorization redirect, so again they on Googles site, this time to do the scopes api confirmation.

So, first question, is that the best practice with most apps with leverage a Google API via OAuth?  To first Authenticate, then possibility Authorize (as needed). Hopefully this will still work ok when things come up with expired/invalid refresh token (fingers crossed the default google library handles that).

When doing the Authorize for consent, can I pass something from the previous Authenticate flow so they don't need to do that again.

Or maybe when doing the Authenticate process (Google Identity Service), there is some flag or param so that if they have already consented, they don't have to do that again on subsequent logins.

Incase I wasn't clear, in a nutshell the question is: should I be doing Authenticate for login, separately from Authorization (oauth2 token).  Or should I go right into the Authorization flow, which first Authenticates the user, and can I skip the Authorization consent screens if they've already done that.  Or maybe there's another way which is the best practice.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Great question. I have been hunting for the answer to this for some time now, and it has constantly defeated me; as has Google's inaccurate, misleading, and incomplete documentation.

Comment: Ok, after more research, I've written up how this is done:
https://www.paultman.com/google-authentication-authorization-via-oauth-in-2022/

Comment: I ended up writing a tutorial also! It's worth noting that even in the best case scenario, it is still a slightly degraded UX over the prior-generation mechanisms. https://overclocked.medium.com/seamless-api-access-with-google-identity-services-b9901009a8ce

Comment: Hey Mr Jackson, interesting how we were both doing about the same thing at the same time and independently wrote it up :-)  
Ironic that it took so much investigation/digging for what should be a common practice. 
Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Hey Paultman -- do you find that the new model is about 6x slower than the old model in clocktime getting through the cycle of Google authentication & authorization?

Answer (score 2):

### Background info

**Authentication** is the act where by a user logs in into a system using their login and password.  With authentication we know that the user is behind the machine. For this we use `Open id connect`, which was built on top of Oauth2.  `Open id connect` returns and `id_token` which can be used to identify the user, it is often a jwt containing some claims to identify the subject or the user behind the Authentication.

The scope used for open id connect is profile and email.  open id connect grants you consent to access a users profile information.

This is an example of the decrypted id token returned by google from a simple call using profile scope only.  All this id token is telling you is who the user behind the machine is.

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "4074087181.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "4074087181.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "1172004755672775346",
  "at_hash": "pYlH4icaIx8PssR32_4qWQ",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20=s96-c",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": 1655219027,
  "exp": 1655222627
}
```

In the same call google also returned an access token.  Now my call contained only the scope for profile, due to the fact that its open id connect. This means that I will only have access to the data that the profile scope would grant access to.  In this case most of what is behind the Google people api.

Note: The user does not see a consent screen with open id connect, even though they are consenting to profile scope.  It is assumed by signing into your account that the system  you are logging into would have access to your profile info.

## Authorization

Authorization is the process by which a user grants your application authorization to access their private user data. The user is shown a consent screen where they consent to your application accessing data defined by some scopes.

[image]

In the case of google calendar api there are serval

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar  See, edit, share, and permanently delete all the calendars you can access using Google Calendar
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events   View and edit events on all your calendars
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly  View events on all your calendars
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly See and download any calendar you can access using your Google Calendar
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly    View your Calendar settings

In this case you are only given an access token this is again Oauth2 it is authorization to access the users calendar data it is not authentication this is not related to login.

## Your question

> So, first question, is that the best practice with most apps with leverage a Google API via OAuth? To first Authenticate, then possibility Authorize (as needed).

You would do both at the same time.

When you authencation your user make sure to include your google calendar scope then the access token and refresh token returned will grant you access to google calendar.

I am going to assume that you have some kind of user system.   When you store the user be sure to store the refresh token that is returned.

As far as Authentication goes i will assume you either have a remember me system which will set a cookie on their machine and remember the user so that you can then get the refresh token from their system the next time they come back.

If they did not chose to select a remember me option then will then have to login every time they visit your site but part of the login will return the `"sub": "1172004755672775346",`  this is the users id on google system so you can use that in your database to match the user when they come back.

Your question is quite complex and will depend upon the type of system you have what it is designed to do as well as what programming language you are using.  That being said I hope this very long answer clears things up a bit.

Comment: First, thanks for your quick response.  Second, thanks for such a comprehensive response.  I have added some example code to further illustrate how/what I am doing.
-- Yes, I would like to do them both A&A at the same time, the problem is that so far the user flow looks identical for the first time (registration), and subsequent logins (which keep including the consent screen which was already approved the first time).
--
I'm going to look deeper into the OpenID connect, as you say that it returns an access token.  Currently, testing with Sign in with google, I get the GWT with user info.

Comment: if I get an access token with Open ID connect, maybe if necessary i simply do incremental Authorization (since I'm adding a few more additional scopes).  That's not what i'm currently doing when I use Sign in With Google (which gives user info in the returned GWT, but not explicitly getting scopes to profile & email).

Comment: Im not the best at JavaScript but i can tell you that you wont get a refresh token back with that.   which means the user will need to be present when you access their data. They are going to have to signin.  You dont need to request profile and email scopes they are probably built into the signin library

Comment: You may want to have a look here https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues There are a few people having issues merging these two systems

Comment: I was hoping this was going to solve a problem, but I think I am still missing something. In the authentication call, where is the access token? There are some opaque looking fields in the JWT, such as azp, aud, jti -- but it's not clear that any of these are an access token. Nor is it clear how to set up the gapi client with that token. I love the idea of "doing both at the same time" -- especially if it can be automatically refreshed. But I still don't see how.

Comment: The JWT you are looking at is an Id token, Id tokens are returned as part of the authentication process (signin) what you are seeing inside are claims.   Authorization is the process where a user grants you access to their data this is Oauth2 and returns an access token.  An access token is not normally a JWT you wont get claims in that the same way.